# Why can't I change the value of this input with .val()?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the value of this disabled input.  I thought maybe the fact that it was disabled was the problem so I removed the disabled attribute manually (in case you were wondering why it is no longer disabled in the screenshot).  See image below:

[image]

From what the console returns it seems to be selecting the input properly, but the value of the input remains blank, even when the input is enabled.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's with the long selector? You can probably just do this: `$('.add-btn:first').next().find('input.product').val( ... )`

Comment: Thanks for the images, but please include the selectors as text too - makes it easier to test and improve the code.

Comment: I faced this issue today for a different scenario, trying to set the value of an input of type range. I had set the max attribute to 2, and was trying to set the val to 3000, way out of range (with step=100). Upon setting, on trying to read the value I was getting 0. However, on trying to set the same val, with max=200 and step=50, it was correctly getting set and getting read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can tell you I have had simmilar issues, and have gotten arround them by using jQuery's attr method. It can set an arbitrary HTML attribute to whatever you want. See more here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: +1 I have no idea why, but `attr` works here where `val` and `prop` both fail.  So strange.

Comment: Not 100% on this, but I think it has something to do with how the jQuery selector returns element(s). When you have the possibility for more than one element to be returned, I find that `.val` tends to fail more often than not.

Comment: a working example would help in addition to provided link of `attr`. thanks though!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: I tested, that doesn't make a difference.  `.val()` should work here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the rest of the page looks like, but I can see that you're nesting tables - might lead to confusion and unexpected results, especially with hidden nested tables. Are you going to show the hidden table when the user clicks the `add-btn`? If so, why not get the text button by looking for it in the click event, relative to the clicked button?

```js
$(".add-btn").click(function(evt){
    var product = getProductNameSomehow(); // Up to you

    var newContainer = $(this).siblings("table").find(".new-row-html");
    newContainer.find("input.product").val(product);

    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

You could improve and generalize this example listener with `$(...).on("click", ...)`. The `.a-btn` would probably be better as a [`<button type="button">Add</button>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button#States_of_the_type_attribute), perhaps [styled as a link](http://natbat.net/2009/Jun/10/styling-buttons-as-links/), if that's what you want, so you wouldn't have to worry about stopping the click event as much.